# How to configure code formatters Beautify, Prettier, per project in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

Are there features that allow formatter configuration to be specific per project in VS Code? As in, I have one project I want indenting, and another project where I don't want indenting. I feel like I read somewhere that was possible, but I'm not finding it now that I'm searching for it.

I'm specifically using Beautify now because it has more configuration options.

Comment: change the formatter settings in the `.vscode/settings.json` file (Workspace settings in the GUI). If the formatter uses a config file, use different configs per project and setup the formatter to use the workspace version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use workspace settings, in VS Code you have `User` settings that are used for every project, and `Workspace` settings (saved in `.vscode/settings.json` in the project folder) that are specific to that project.

If you want to share workspace settings with others you can commit `.vscode/settings.json`.

You can edit both settings directly on the `.json` files, or through the VS Code settings editor (Files->Preferences->Settings).